# display information from sql server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

New to views with sql server, not sure how to view the information it has gathered with vbscript.  I know it is not as simple as:

```
select * from EXAMPLE_VIEW
```

I want to get the information from my example view loop through it and display it, however when i try to do that sql query i get invalid object name.

My question is how do you sql query a view

Comment: Show us your code, at least the relevant portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be doing this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM dbo.EXAMPLE_VIEW;
```

This is because if your user has a different default schema than dbo, it might be checking for some other view with the same name under a different schema. (You also know not to use SELECT *, right?)

So you should also make sure your user account has select permissions on the view and/or the table(s) behind it.

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from EXAMPLE_VIEW
```

...**is** the correct way to query a SQL Server view.

If it's not working for you, you have a different kind of problem: maybe no permissions, maybe no server connection, maybe a view called `EXAMPLE_VIEW` doesn't exist, maybe something else.
Whatever it is - we need the exact error message and as much example code as possible to help you.

But the SQL itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is your current database set correctly after establishing connection? It can be set using connnection string (http://www.connectionstrings.com/) or by specyfying it witin query itself:

```
SELECT * FROM MYDB.dbo.EXAMPLE_VIEW;
```